# How do I test my Angular scope functions in karma + jasmine?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I'm fairly new to Angular and very new to Jasmine testing. I have a function in my controller at pushes an object into an empty array (object taken from json data).

my controller with the functions pertaining to the cart:

```
$scope.cart = [];

  $scope.addItemToCart = function(choc) {
    var cartItem = readCartItem(choc.id);
    if(cartItem == null) {
      //if item doesn't exist, add to cart array
      $scope.cart.push({type: choc.type, id: choc.id, price: choc.price, quantity: 1})
    } else {
      //increase quantity
      cartItem.quantity++;
    }
  }

  $scope.cartTotal = function() {
    var sum = 0;
    $scope.cart.forEach(function(item) {
      sum += item.price * item.quantity;
    });
    return sum;
  }

  $scope.getTotalQuantity = function() {
    var totalItems = 0;
    $scope.cart.forEach(function(item) {
      totalItems += item.quantity;
    });
    return totalItems;
  }

  $scope.clearCart = function() {
    $scope.cart.length = 0;
  }

  $scope.removeItem = function(choc) {
    $scope.cart.splice(choc,1);
  }

  function readCartItem(id) {
    //iterate thru cart and read ID
    for(var i=0; i<$scope.cart.length; i++) {
      if($scope.cart[i].id === id) {
        return $scope.cart[i]
      }
    }
    return null;
  }
```

My test:

```
  describe('Controller: ChocoListCtrl', function () {

  beforeEach(module('App'));

  var scope, ctrl, json;

  beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $rootScope) {


    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    // ChocoListCtrl = $controller('ChocoListCtrl', {});
    ctrl = $controller("ChocoListCtrl", { $scope:scope })
  }));

  it('should be defined', function (){
    expect(ctrl).toBeDefined();
  });

  it('should have an empty cart', function(){
    expect(scope.cart.length).toBeLessThan(1);
  });

  describe('cart functions', function(){
    beforeEach(function(){
      scope.addItemToCart();
    })

    it('should add objects into the cart', function(){
      expect(scope.cart.length).toBeGreaterThan(0);
    })
  });
```

The error I come back with when running the test:

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'choc.id')
```

I thought I was pushing an object into the array? Am I missing something? Should I include the JSON file if it helps?

Any guidance would help. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not passing in a parameter to `$scope.addItemToCart`. So when it tries to read `choc` it can't because it's `undefined`.

This line is causing the error:

```
beforeEach(function(){
  scope.addItemToCart(); // No parameter being passed in
})
```

Comment: Haha, no problem, we all do it, and we all need our coffee too!